# Offline voice recognition API in Android 4.2

Tags: android, voice, voice-recognition

I want to create application that uses offline Android's builtin voice recognition API. Does anyone have an example? I've tried to use RecognizerIntent API but it still requires internet. I've looked here: https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-typing-integration/. In file ActivityHelper.java they use RecognizerIntent API too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reasonably confident that offline speech recognition is a Google Voice Typing-only feature. Unless you install something that provides offline recognition APIs, the built-in recognition system will require an Internet connection.

Answer (score -1):

you could use voice control without internet. Just seach "Voice control without internet".

It's a self assigned commands with the use of phoenetic alphabets.